# Firemonkey: Change Virtual Keyboard Enter button according to edit

Tags: keyboard, firemonkey

I'm using RadStudio 10.1 Berlin and I'm tryng to change the Key Enter of my Virtual Keyboard when search edit is pressed. Now what I get is this enter button:

[image: what I have]

But I want change for something like this:

[image: What I want]

or this:

[image: What I want]

or this

[image: What I want]

I know about the keyboardType option on the inspector, but there's nothing there about search, or next. Just E-mail, phonenumber, alphabetic, default etc...

Comment: See `ReturnKeyType` property

Comment: Thank you, fixed my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only change **ReturnKeyType** = Next for example.